# Qt - dependent class

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

I've added a class to my project. After some time I resigned from that class and removed both source and header (from Qt Designer). Class is not included or imported anywhere, but when I build project, i'm getting message:

```
:-1: error: dependent 'C:\Qt\Project\dists\registration.h' does not exist.
```

I tried to search for registration.h over all files in project, deleted debug folder. There are no any result. Class is not referenced anywhere. Still can't build project.

Where are these hell dependencies then?

Comment: If you deleted the build folder and error didn't vanished, `registration.h` surely is mentioned somewhere in your source folder. Try full text search over all files.

Comment: Look for the HEADERS line in your project file.

Comment: Nope, that was deleted by QT Designer I think (there are no line with registration[.h][.cpp] anywhere in project file).

Comment: Have you tried to clean, rebuild?

Comment: Worth trying with/without Shadow Build.

Comment: Problem solved, explaination in my response. Still don't know why it happened, but I can go forward with project...

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I've figured it out. Strange...

I've removed files `dists.pro.user` and `dists.pro.user.ddfc87e`.
After new project configuration it started to work (if someone knows why, will be great to know it... )

Thanks for attention ;)

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of those who will seek for the answer later, there is another way to fix that.

> I tried to search for registration.h over all files in project,
>   deleted debug folder. There are no any result. Class is not referenced
>   anywhere. Still can't build project.

If you search in all files of the project, using * to seek for all types of files, you will find makefiles that still use these references.

The simple way to get rid of the error is to run qmake on the project in QtCreator. It rewrites these makefiles.

Comment: I had this problem too, I got an API folder (indicated in the .pro with a env var) which evolved and removed one header. **There was indeed occurences in makefiles**, but **qmake didn't solve it**. I had to delete manually the makefiles. Interesting note : With this problem, you must **search in all files with an other software that QtCreator** because you never find makefiles in its searches.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem,
but i did find the error.

it's because of your `.pro` file still has the file `C:\Qt\Project\dists\registration.h`

you have to remove that file from `HEADERS` in your `.pro`

then clean your project 
and qmake it 
and compile it.
then it will work.