# dependent '... .ui' does not exist

Tags: c++, qt

So, basically, I've decided to a bit organize my resources. I'm pretty new to Qt so I've decided to do it by hands by creating folders and putting files in them directly.
Ofc I wrote paths in `#include` but Qt still puts an error to me which I described in title

Here's my .pro file, pls help:

```
    QT       += core gui
    
    greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
    CONFIG += c++17
    
    #DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0
    
    SOURCES += \
        AdminPanel/adminpanel.cpp \
        PhotoReporterAdminPanel/photoreporteradminpanel.cpp \
        main.cpp \
        photoreporteradminpanel.cpp
    
    HEADERS += \
        AdminPanel/adminpanel.h \
        PhotoReporterAdminPanel/photoreporteradminpanel.h \
        photoreporteradminpanel.h
    
    FORMS += \
        AdminPanel/adminpanel.ui \
        PhotoReporterAdminPanel/photoreporteradminpanel.ui \
        photoreporteradminpanel.ui
    
    # Default rules for deployment.
    qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
    else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
    !isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

---

Here's how hierarchy looks like:

```
CourseWork
|
|>PhotoReporterAdminPanel
|    |
|    |>AdminPanel
|    |    |>adminpanel.h, adminpanel.cpp, adminpanel.ui
|    |>PhotoReporterAdminPanel
|    |    |>PhotoReporterAdminPanel.h, PhotoReporterAdminPanel.cpp, PhotoReporterAdminPanel.ui
|    |>main.cpp, PhotoReporterAdminPanel.pro
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider taking the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), especially regarding [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make it easier for people to assist you, thus improving your chances at getting an answer. In your particular case, please make sure to include the entire text of the error message (as provided by the compiler) in your question.

Comment: Why `photoreporteradminpanel.ui` is provided with and without parent directory?

Answer (score -1):

your problem solved in this question
[Qt - dependent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222447/qt-dependent-class)

I've had like this problem you should solve dependencies and delete build folder and re build